# OPSS to Manage (Authentication / Subscription Changes) Users

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I am using Oracle WebLogic server to host our applications. We have a requirement to manage user subscriptions - identify password changes, renew expired password, accounts, etc. - at the application level.

We are using WebLogic 11g and Microsoft Active Directory as the identity provider. After going through Oracle documentation, I realized that it's better to use OPSS to achieve this as we are using Oracle solutions. However, still I could not figure out a way to achieve this using Java, OPSS and Active Directory.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: There are some pretty good examples out there like: http://biemond.blogspot.com/2013/01/active-directory-user-management-with.html Do you have a more specific question/problem?

Comment: Thats what I exactly wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. If there is some specific piece of information from that link that you end up using, you can answer your own question and post the details =)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use OPSS (Oracle Platform Security Service) based implementations, you need to have SSL established between the application server (WebLogic) and the Identity Store (Active Directory).

The below will detailed out the implementation I did - removed some specific information to simplify it.

#### Obtain the IdentityStore Object

```
JpsContext           jpsContext     = null;
IdentityStoreService isService      = null;
LdapIdentityStore    idstoreService = null;

jpsContext      = JpsContextFactory.getContextFactory().getContext();
isService       = jpsContext.getServiceInstance(IdentityStoreService.class);
idstoreService  = (LdapIdentityStore)
                  jpsContext.getServiceInstance(IdentityStoreService.class);
idStore         = idstoreService.getIdmStore();
```

#### Extract the User

```
String userName = “testUser”;
User user    = null;

searchFilter    = idStore.getSimpleSearchFilter(UserProfile.USER_NAME, SimpleSearchFilter.TYPE_EQUAL, null);
searchFilter.setValue(userName + searchFilter.getWildCardChar());

params = new SearchParameters();
params.setFilter(searchFilter);

SearchResponse resp = idStore.searchUsers(params);
// Load the searched user details
while (resp.hasNext()) {
   user = (User)resp.next();
   if (user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
       // User Found
       break;
   }
}
```

#### Extract the User Profile

`UserProfile userProfile = user.getUserProfile();`

Afterwards, you can perform changes to the extracted user such as, password change, reset, etc.

 Hope this helps for someone in the future.